# Google Streetview - No French images working?

Tags: google-maps, google-street-view

I am attempting to use the Google Streetview API to grab streetview images.  My code works for every country except France.  For some reason, when I try to grab data from anywhere in France, I just get back the gray image that says "Sorry, we have no imagery here."  But, I know there is imagery there because I can use the google streetview via your google website and see the streetview.

For example, if I go to https://maps.google.com/maps/ms?ie=UTF8&oe=UTF8&msa=0&msid=101555744172859669534.00044f7fe84800c56d7a6&dg=feature and input the GPS coordinates "48.856638,2.352241", I can see the streetview data.  However, if I go to [http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=308x263&location=2.352241,48.856638&fov=120&key=[myAPIkey]](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=308x263&location=2.352241,48.856638&fov=120&key=%5bmyAPIkey%5d) I get back the gray image that says "Sorry, we have no imagery here."  I have also tried reversing the order of the GPS coordinates in the URL string (i.e., "48.856638,2.352241"), and I still get back the image that says "Sorry, we have no imagery here."

Any idea what I'm doing wrong or why this might be occurring?

Comment: Haha.  After I posted this question, I thought to myself "I'm going to get a ton of anti-France responses....aren't i..."

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're not getting an image because the coordinates are in the middle of a building.  Try moving them to a street, like 48.857213,2.352617 and you should then get an image.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=308x263&location=48.857213,2.352617&fov=120

Comment: That's very odd --- then why do those coordinates show something when using streetview through the Google website? In any event, it does appear that the coordinates you sent work, so that must be the problem.  thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you enter coordinates that are slightly wrong on Google Maps it will redirect you to the nearest working coordinates automatically. The api also has a function for near or close to.